# Javascript boolean "toggle"

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I have a function which looks at a cursor (x, y) to see if it falls within one of several rectangles (`a<x<b, c<y<d`). However, I need to set a boolean based on whether the cursor *ever fell* into a particular rectangle and only reset it when the cursor falls into some other rectangles. In other words

1. A is true if cursor fall within rectangle X
2. A is false if cursor falls within rectangle 1, 2, 3 or 4
3. A retains its former value if it's anywhere but Y or Z

The trouble is no matter what I do the boolean returns false if I leave the first rectangle, whether I visit the other 2 rectangles or not. I tried making the boolean global but that was no help.

Code;

```
var r
var s
var l
var inCenter = false

function makeRects(a,b)


{       
    r = a-b
    s = (a/2) - (b/2)
    l = (a/2) + (b/2)

    lSide = new Array(4)
    lSide[0] = 0
    lSide[1] = 0
    lSide[2] = a
    lSide[3] = b

    tSide = new Array(4)
    tSide[0] = 0
    tSide[1] = 0
    tSide[2] = b
    tSide[3] = a

    rSide = new Array(4)
    rSide[0] = r
    rSide[1] = 0
    rSide[2] = b
    rSide[3] = b

    bSide = new Array(4)
    bSide[0] = 0
    bSide[1] = r
    bSide[2] = b
    bSide[3] = b

    aSquare = new Array(4)
    aSquare[0] = 0
    aSquare[1] = 0
    aSquare[2] = s
    aSquare[3] = s

    bSquare = new Array(4)
    bSquare[0] = l
    bSquare[1] = 0
    bSquare[2] = b
    bSquare[3] = s

    cSquare = new Array(4)
    cSquare[0] = 0
    cSquare[1] = l
    cSquare[2] = s
    cSquare[3] = r

    dSquare = new Array(4)
    dSquare[0] = l
    dSquare[1] = l
    dSquare[2] = r
    dSquare[3] = r

    lCenter = new Array(4)
    lCenter[0] = 0
    lCenter[1] = s
    lCenter[2] = b
    lCenter[3] = l

    tCenter = new Array(4)
    tCenter[0] = s
    tCenter[1] = 0
    tCenter[2] = l
    tCenter[3] = b

    rCenter = new Array(4)
    rCenter[0] = r
    rCenter[1] = s
    rCenter[2] = a
    rCenter[3] = l

    bCenter = new Array(4)
    bCenter[0] = s
    bCenter[1] = r
    bCenter[2] = l
    bCenter[3] = a

    mCenter = new Array(4)
    mCenter[0] = s
    mCenter[1] = s
    mCenter[2] = l
    mCenter[3] = l
} 

function cursor(a,b) 

{
    var inaSquare = false
    var inbSquare = false
    var incSquare = false
    var indSquare = false
    var inCenter = false

    if ((a>aSquare[0] && a<aSquare[2])&&(b>aSquare[1] && b<aSquare[3]))
    {
    inaSquare = true
    post("aSquare");
    post();
    }

    if ((a>bSquare[0] && a<bSquare[2])&&(b>bSquare[1] && b<bSquare[3]))
    {
    inbSquare = true
    post("bSquare");
    post();
    }

    if ((a>cSquare[0] && a<cSquare[2])&&(b>cSquare[1] && b<cSquare[3]))
    {
    inbSquare = true
    post("cSquare");
    post();
    }

    if ((a>dSquare[0] && a<dSquare[2])&&(b>dSquare[1] && b<dSquare[3]))
    {
    indSquare = true
    post("dSquare");
    post();
    }

    if (inaSquare||inbSquare||incSquare||indSquare)
    {
    inCenter = false
    }

    if ((a>mCenter[0] && a<mCenter[2])&&(b>mCenter[1] && b<mCenter[3]))
    {
    inCenter = true
    inaSquare = false
    inbSquare = false
    incSquare = false
    indSquare = false
    }

    if (((inCenter && a>s) && a<l) && b<lCenter[3])

    {
    outlet (1, 1)
    }

    else if (((inCenter && a>s) && a<l) && b>rCenter[0])

    {
    outlet (1, 2)
    }

    else if (((inCenter && b>s) && b<l) && a<tCenter[3])

    {
    outlet (1, 3)
    }


    else if (((inCenter && b>s) && b<l) && b>bCenter[1])

    {
    outlet (1, 4)
    }

    else

    {
    outlet (1, 0)
    }
    post("inCenter");
    post(inCenter);
    post();
    post("inaSquare");
    post(inaSquare);
    post();
    post("inbSquare");
    post(inbSquare);
    post();
    post("incSquare");
    post(incSquare);
    post();
    post("indSquare");
    post(indSquare);
    post();

}
```

Comment: Can you post this function you speak of?

Comment: Where is your code? My crystal ball is broken, and I ordered a new one only yesterday :(

Comment: Might be a good idea to edit the question to include what code you have at the moment.

Comment: Sorry folks, my code is pretty large and I was hoping to avoid it. Let me go chop it up.

Comment: It doesn't look to be under 50 lines at best, think I can pastebin?

Comment: Use loops in your code and we will read it.

Comment: I don't really know how to do that here, all the elements are unique, sorry

Comment: I don't fully understand, but a couple thoughts. 1. If the below did answer it, checking it resolved would help. 2. As mentioned below if element are unique put them in an array to loop through.  3. if you don't want to continue, return to exit the function or break/continue from loop prevents further execution. But you said you can't make the boolean global - googling variable scope would explain that, but in this case, although not the best implementation, just declare the variable outside the function.  PS - jsfiddle is your friend for Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

Well sorry this isn't a real answer, but I've edited your code to use loops and arrays/maps. That way you may be able to get some more help. Hope you'll be able to learn something from it as well :)

So your code could also look like this:

```
var r
var s
var l

function makeRects(a,b)
{  
    r = a-b
    s = (a/2) - (b/2)
    l = (a/2) + (b/2)

    // Place all arrays inside maps, so that we can loop through them later.
    side = {
        l: [0, 0, a, b],
        t: [0, 0, b, a],
        r: [r, 0, b, b],
        b: [0, r, b, b],
    }

    square = {
        a: [0, 0, s, s],
        b: [l, 0, b, s],
        c: [0, l, s, r],
        d: [l, l, r, r]
    }

    center = {
        l: [0, s, b, l],
        t: [s, 0, l, b],
        r: [r, s, a, l],
        b: [s, r, l, a],
        m: [s, s, l, l]
    }
}

function cursor(a,b)
{
    var inside = {
        a: false,
        b: false,
        c: false,
        d: false,
        center: true
    }

    // This loop will run through every key of the map, and x will hold the key
    for (var x in square) {
        if ((a>square[a][x] && a<square[x][2])&&(b>square[x][1] && b<square[x][3]))
        {
            inside[x] = true;
            // Instead of checking if the cursor is inside the center, we assume it
            // is by default, and if it is found inside a square, inside['center'] is set to false
            inside['center'] = false;
            post(x + "Square");
            post();
        }
    }

    // Not sure what you want to do here...
    if (((inside['center'] && a>s) && a<l) && b<center['l'][3])
    {
    outlet (1, 1)
    }

    else if (((inside['center'] && a>s) && a<l) && b>center['r'][0])
    {
    outlet (1, 2)
    }

    else if (((inside['center'] && b>s) && b<l) && a<center['t'][3])
    {
    outlet (1, 3)
    }


    else if (((inside['center'] && b>s) && b<l) && b>center['b'][1])
    {
    outlet (1, 4)
    }

    else
    {
    outlet (1, 0)
    }


}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Re your question that was exactly what I was asking. When the cursor goes in the center, I want to make a global bool called inCenter true. It cannot be incenter by default - I need it to see if I go into a center square with a side equal to b to set it to true. _Once it's true_ I can start listening for the other squares, which should set it to false. It stays true unless the other squares are visited.

Comment: The outlets are methods unique to the environment, for practical purposes they can be replaced by alert(whatever).

Answer (score 0):

okay i modified the original demo based on what i think you are trying to accomplish but it still isn't very clear so you need to better describe what you are trying to accomplish rather than how to toggle boolean based on rectangle coordinate hit testing.  it's possible that what you are trying to accomplish could be done in a simpler way without resorting to coordinate based hit tests.

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/DaveAlger/cVPpU/5/

html:

```
<p id="toggle-state">false: center not hit</p>
<p id="mouse-xy"></p>

<canvas id="top" class="box" x="200" y="50" width="100" height="100" c="#933" b="#faa"></canvas>
<canvas id="left" class="box" x="50" y="200" width="100" height="100" c="#993" b="#ffa"></canvas>
<canvas id="right" class="box" x="350" y="200" width="100" height="100" c="#696" b="#dfd"></canvas>
<canvas id="bottom" class="box" x="200" y="350" width="100" height="100" c="#369" b="#adf"></canvas>
<canvas id="center" class="box" x="200" y="200" width="100" height="100" c="#999" b="#ddd"></canvas>
```

css:

```
.box{position: absolute;}
#mouse-xy{float:right;padding:30px;color:#999;font-family:sans-serif;}
```

js:

```
var isCenterHit = false;
var checkCenterHit = true;

// draw canvas rectangles
$('.box').each(function(i) {
    //alert(i);
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    var w = $(this).width();
    var h = $(this).height();
    var c = $(this).attr('c');
    var x = $(this).attr('x');
    var y = $(this).attr('y');

    drawRect( document.getElementById( id ).getContext('2d'), w, h, c, id );
    $(this).offset({top: y, left: x});
});

function drawRect( ctx, width, height, color, text ) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = '30px sans-serif';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);
}

// listen for mouse over
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;

    var tX = $(e.target).attr('x');
    var tY = $(e.target).attr('y');
    var tW = $(e.target).width();
    var tH = $(e.target).height();

    // update mouse location
    $('#mouse-xy').html("center hit: " + isCenterHit + "  |  X: " + x + " Y: " + y);

    // rectangle coordinate hit test (this can be done other ways too)
    if ( x > tX && x < tX + tW && y > tY && y < tY + tH ) {

        // toggle the boolean
        if ( checkCenterHit && $(e.target).attr('id') === 'center' ) {
            isCenterHit = !isCenterHit;
            checkCenterHit = false;
        }

        if ( isCenterHit ) {
            // do this when center hit state is 'on'
            $('body').css('background-color',$(e.target).attr('b'));
            $('canvas').css('cursor','pointer');
        } else {
            // do this when center hit state is 'off'
            $('body').css('background-color','');
            $('canvas').css('cursor','');
        }
    }
    else {
        $('body').css('background-color','#ffffff');
        checkCenterHit = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is great, but unfortunately the hit event needs to live in the script and set toggle

Comment: please check out the updated fiddle.  i'm not exactly sure what you mean by "live in the script" this example is almost 100% script only the canvas elements are html but those can be created dynamically in the script too if needed

Comment: this fiddle shows that by only adding more rectangles everything still works the same where each time the center rectangle is hit the boolean toggles on and off changing the behavior for all the others...

http://jsfiddle.net/DaveAlger/cVPpU/6/

Answer (score 0):

probably your hit test function needs to have a flag called `doTest` set to true initially and then set to false once the center rectangle is hit

then you can set `doTest` to true again once a different rectangle is hit